# Has there been any Force users with the ability to use battle meditation after the Ruusan Reformation?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force

This question is referring to any of the media, current canon or Legends.

In the old republic era, there were a few Force users with the ability to change the tide of the battle by using the force.  In the Knights of the Old Republic series Bastila was one, and in the Darth Bane series there were a couple.  After the Ruusan reformation the Jedi military was mostly disbanded and they became like the Jedi in the movies.  Was this technique ever used again be Jedi during the Clone Wars or the Legends Expanded Universe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes

In Legends, many post-Ruusan Jedi have had this ability.

The most notable is **Luke Skywalker himself**. In the audio drama *Dark Empire II*, Luke discovers a text detailing the art of Battle Meditation:

> KAM: Luke, look at this book! Can you read what it says?
>
> LUKE: A little. Something about....”Jedi Battle Meditation.” I should
> study this book. I should study all these books.
>
> <sub>*Star Wars: Dark Empire II*</sub>

We can assume he eventually read it. Given his innate Force powers, it seems highly probable that he mastered the art.

We can’t forget **Leia Organa**, who also learned this art from an old book:

> LEIA:  The Emperor’s here!  He wants us!  He wants our children!
>
> HAN:  Blast that scum!  If I ever get him in my sights, he’s rancor
> food!
>
> LEIA:  I don’t need a blaster.  Not with what I’ve just learned about
> Jedi Battle Meditation.
>
> <sub>*Star Wars: Empire’s End*</sub>

There are various others, but these are probably the highest-profile practitioners.

Comment: While ambiguously canon, [Diala Pasil](http://imperial-assault.wikia.com/wiki/Diala_Passil_(Hero)) from the board game [Star Wars: Imperial Assault](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Imperial_Assault_Core_Set) can learn Battle Meditation.

Comment: Don't forget jedi council member Oppo Rancisis. His skill at battle meditation was invaluable to the republic before his death on Saleucami.

Comment: @FerusOlin - There are many others listed on the wiki and elsewhere. These are  just the two best-known, and particularly unambiguous.

Comment: @FerusOlin - I may have overlooked something, but according to [his Wookieepedia entry](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Oppo_Rancisis), Oppo Rancisis survived Saleucami *and* Order 66.

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon Adamant's answer a bit to provide a "definitive" answer from the current (2021) canon, according to Wookieepedia, [Battle Meditation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_Meditation) was a somewhat rare, but not altogether unheard of ability among Force users.

## Clone Wars Era (22–19 BBY)

According to the linked Wookieepedia article:

> During the Clone Wars, **[Adi Gallia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Adi_Gallia)** used battle meditation whilst piloting her Delta-7B Aethersprite-class light interceptor alongside a V-19 Torrent starfighter. During his training on Dagobah, **[Luke Skywalker](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Luke_Skywalker)** used battle meditation while lifting several rocks telekinetically using the Force.
>
> Jedi Masters **[Mace Windu](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mace_Windu)** and **[Oppo Rancisis](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Oppo_Rancisis)** were skilled in battle meditation.

As mentioned in Ferus Olin's comment to the previous answer, Oppo Rancisis used his Battle Meditation to help Jedi General [Quinlan Vos](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Quinlan_Vos) to defeat the Separatist forces at the [Siege of Saleucami](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Siege_of_Saleucami).

## High Republic Era (approximately 300 BBY to 82 BBY)

Additionally, while it hasn't been *explicitly* referred to by that name (yet), I believe an argument can be made that Jedi Master **[Avar Kriss](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Avar_Kriss)** was absolutely skilled in the practice of Battle Meditation. Avar Kriss lived during the [High Republic era](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/High_Republic_Era), whereas, according to Legends (*we haven't been given a specific time frame for the event as of yet in [current canon](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ruusan_Reformations)*) the [Ruusan Reformation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ruusan_Reformation) took place *ca.* 1000 BBY.

From the linked Wookieepedia article (*emphasis mine*):

> Kriss proceeded to float a meter above the deck of the Third Horizon's bridge, ***reaching out to the Force to form a network in the Force to act as the point of connection for the Jedi in the system***.

This, to me, sounds very similar to the descriptions of Battle Meditation from the various Legends sources I've read, as well as the canon description of the ability which states:

> Battle Meditation was a Force ability, rare among Jedi, that could be used to form connections to those around them and transfer images, sensations, locations, and at times even simple ideas.